# NGINX configuratuion for automatic pretty links for multiple wordpress sites in subdirectories

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, configuration, permalinks

I have a dev server where I upload client websites, every WordPress site has its own DB and directory (every site is independent). I have one server block. My problem is with the pretty permalinks, this works for me:

```
    server_name dev.example.tld;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-$
            expires off;
    }

    location /site_1/ {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /site_1/index.php?$args;
    }

    location /site_2/ {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /site_2/index.php?$args;
    }
```

I've been searching for a way to do it one time instead of adding the location block for each site but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `location` into a regular expression and capture the site name:

```
location ~ ^(?<site>/[^/]+) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $site/index.php?$args;
}
```

Alternatively, accomplish the same effect by using a rewrite:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+) $1/index.php last;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: the `site` variable is the url e.g. **dev.example.tld** ? 
when I used it shows an error :

Comment: Sorry, cut & paste error in the second example, it should of course be `$1`. The `$site` or `$1` is the first path segment of the URI - e.g. `/site_1` or `/site_2` in your case. If you need the server name use: `$host`, `$server_name` or `$http_host` (which are all slightly different - see [this link for details](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host))